# Jemand, der diskriminiert, ist ein …?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-word-request

Wie nennt man jemanden, der diskriminiert? „Diskriminator“ vielleicht?

Comment: In der Sozialwissenschaft: Durchaus, da gibt es diesen Fachbegriff. Im täglichen Leben:  Mir fällt kein Wort dazu ein - Da werden spezifischere Begriffe benutzt: Chauvinist, Rassist, ...

Comment: Nur zur Ergänzung: außerhalb der Sozialwissenschaften ist ein Diskriminator ein elektronisches Bauteil. Da wären die von @tofro erwähnten spezifischen Begriffe eindeutiger

Comment: Der »Bot« sollte dich nicht dazu animieren, sinnloses Geschwätz zu fabrizieren. Stattdessen hätte ich von dir lieber erfahren, welche anderen Möglichkeiten anstelle von »Diskriminator« du in Betracht ziehst, und warum du ob deiner Vermutung so unsicher bist, dass du nachfragen musst. Auch höchst interessant (und wichtig für uns um eine passende Antwort zu finden) ist der Kontext, innerhalb dessen du gedenkst, dieses Wort zu verwenden. Weil all das fehlt, hast du von mir -1 bekommen. Editiere deine Frage und ergänze sie mit *sinnvollen* Informationen, dann werde ich meine Bewertung überdenken.

Comment: Verächter. Aber ausdrücklich: kein Synonym! Ansonsten würde ich Diskriminant (eigene Wortschöpfung) dem Diskriminator vorziehen. Analog Diskutant, Disputant, Informant. Nicht: Elefant.

Comment: Ich glaube, eine, die diskriminiert, ist eine [Diskriminante](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskriminante).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Diskriminator scheint das passende Wort zu sein.

So nennt Wikipedia im [Diskriminierungsartikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskriminierung) den Begriff Diskriminator.
Der [Artikel zu Diskriminator](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskriminator) beschreibt den Begriff Diskriminator in der Nachrichtentechnik, verweist aber auch auf:

> Zum Diskriminator als Täter der sozialen Diskriminierung siehe Soziale Diskriminierung.

Meine persönliche erste Antwort auf die Frage wäre *Diskriminierer* in Sinne von: *Der Diskriminierer machte mich mit seiner Diskriminierung zum Diskriminierten*.

Es gibt [Übersetzungsvorschläge zu Diskriminierer](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Diskriminierer), In der Welt [soll es folgenden Eintrag gegeben haben](http://www.mydict.com/Wort/Diskriminierer/):

> Und auch der Diskriminierer eines Diskriminierers darf nicht als Diskriminierdiskriminierer diskriminiert werden.( Quelle: Die Welt vom 22.01.2005 )

Als Übersicht der Begiffe:

- Wer diskriminiert: Diskriminator oder Diskriminierer oder auch Diskriminierender
- Die Tat: Diskriminierung, bzw. als Verb diskriminieren
- Das Opfer: Diskriminierte

Answer (score 3):

Zwar wären *Diskriminierer, Diskriminator* oder *Diskriminierende(r)* möglich, sind aber allesamt eher unüblich. Wenn vorhanden wird stattdessen ein spezialisierter Begriff bevorzugt, der auf dem Merkmal bzw. Vorurteil basiert anhand dessen jemand andere diskriminiert, v.a. ***Rassist*** und ***Sexist***. Das korreliert mit den entsprechenden [„Ismen“](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ismus#Ismen_als_Geisteshaltung_und_Lebenseinstellung), aber nicht für jeden *…-smus* ist auch *…-ist* als „Täter“ üblich. Etwas allgemeiner wäre ***Chauvi*** bzw. ***Chauvinist***.